# Which jpeg delegate to install, and what are the installation steps in CentOS?

Tags: linux, delegates, centos, imagemagick

I am trying to install imagemagick and jpeg delegate to a CentOS machine that I do not have sudo access to. The first thing I tried was to install imagemagick by doing

```
./configure --prefix=[path]
make
make install
```

In the resulting installation jpeg delegate was missing.

```
DELEGATES       = bzlib mpeg fontconfig freetype lzma png ps x xml zlib
```

Through old forum posts I was directed to http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/. None of the posts were actually mentioning which exact file to download and install. So I grabbed `jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz` and `openjpeg-2.0.0.tar.gz`, installed them, again to custom prefix that was on my `PATH` and re-built imagemagick. Yet the jpeg delegate was still missing. Can I get an explanation of what exactly am I doing wrong and what should I be doing to make this work?

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, download the `jpeg` delegate as you have, then unpack it and go into the directory where you unpacked it and run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/jpeg
make && make install
```

You can use a different directory from `$HOME/jpeg` but be consistent in the next step.

Now download the **ImageMagick** source, unpack and go into the directory where you unpacked it:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/ImageMagick --with-jpeg=yes CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/jpeg/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/jpeg/lib"
make clean
make -j4 && make install
```

That's it.

Comment: Great answer Mark! I would also suggest `make clean` before attempting to re-configure IM. Just to ensure MagickCore is rebuild with jpeg coder registered.

Comment: @emcconville Thanks, Eric. I have updated per your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still unsure which one is the correct jpeg delegate though

Comment: @OganM I used the v9 one to test the above.